# Invalid Key length 16 bytes : in Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans

I am getting Invalid key length: 16 bytes on netbeans ide by using this code as follows

```
SecretKey deskey = new SecretKeySpec(keybyte, "DESede/ECB/NOPADDING");
Cipher c1 = Cipher.getInstance("DESede/ECB/NOPADDING");
c1.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, deskey);
```

but the same code works well in android in eclipse..

Comment: Check the JRE config for both IDEs. Are they the same? Try upgrading the JRE

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that 16 bytes (which means 128 bits) is not a valid key size for DESede (aka Triple DES) anyway, so I would expect this code block to fail on the runtime. I don't know why it's working in android or eclipse as you said (haven't tried it myself yet). A quick research tells me that Triple DES's key size is 168, 112, or 56 bits, so probably you should change the size of `keybyte` to 21, 14, or 7 bytes.

Also, you shouldn't use ECB in production, since it's insecure. Using NoPadding is also a bad idea for ECB mode, since you cannot encrypt plaintext of any length then. Refer to https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/20941/why-shouldnt-i-use-ecb-encryption for more information. My suggestion is `"AES/CTR/NoPadding"` as the cipher algorithm and append the IV in front of the ciphertext. If you are restricted to Triple DES, `"DESede/CTR/NoPadding"` might work for you.

Reference: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_DES